# In what table of the SOA_Infra database can I find the composite sensor data?

Tags: database, oracle12c, bpel, soa-suite

**question background:** I want to get usage data from certain operations that I adress through a referenced service in my BPEL. In order to get usage data I have added BPEL composite sensors to the composite and have filled them with element values used in the operations. My goal is to write a SQL statement in order to get a count of the specific operations usage rate.

**Actual Question:** In what table in the SOA_Infra database can I find the composite sensor data?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

This may help:
https://soaarchitecture.wordpress.com/2018/04/02/soa-infra-usefull-everyday-queries-12c/. Also check the docs for the public views that are exposed. Most likely the base tables won't be mentioned in the docs.